# How to do multi platform compiling with fpc?

Tags: cmd, freepascal

How to generate an ios or android executable after compiling with free pacal on windows using command line?

I usually do this to compile files :

C:/fpc/path/to/compiler.exe C:/path/to/file.pas

But that command will just create a windows executable.

Comment: To my best knowledge you'll need a mac for iOS

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a good Android tutorial on how to set-up Android SDK and how to compile an example app using Lazarus IDE: [Free Pascal - Android Tutorial](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Android_tutorial)

Also you have it for iPhone: [Free Pascal - iOs Tutorial](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/iPhone/iPod_development)